# pandas: groupwise normalize

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

let's have a DataFrame

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({'A': (1,2,3,1,2,3),
                    'B': [10*i for i in range(6)],
                    'C': ("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b")}).set_index(["C", "A"])
```

```
      B
C A    
a 1   0
  2  10
  3  20
b 1  30
  2  40
  3  50
```

I'd need to interpret column B as value normed by value B of second index "A" == 2.

```
         B
C A       
a 1  0.000
  2  1.000
  3  2.000
b 1  0.750
  2  1.000
  3  1.200
```

It looks so easy. I've experimented with groupby, transform ... and cannot make it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is first get only `2` in second level by [`Series.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.xs.html) and dived mapped first level by [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
s = dft['B'].xs(2, level=1)

dft['B'] = dft['B'].div(dft.index.droplevel(-1).map(s))
print (dft)
        B
C A      
a 1  0.00
  2  1.00
  3  2.00
b 1  0.75
  2  1.00
  3  1.25
```

Another idea is use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for replace `B` values to `NaN` if no `2` in `A level` and then divide with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
s1 = dft['B'].where(dft.index.get_level_values(1) == 2)
dft['B'] = dft['B'].div(s1.groupby(level=0).transform('first'))
print (dft)
        B
C A      
a 1  0.00
  2  1.00
  3  2.00
b 1  0.75
  2  1.00
  3  1.25
```

Comment: Thanks! It is really not so straightforward as I hoped... Why did you use `droplevel(-1)` instead of `droplevel(1)` ?

Comment: @HonzaS. - It working same - second or last value. So working same if `droplevel(1)` or `droplevel(-1)` if 2 levels.